# Haskell: Is (MonadPlus m => Bool -> a -> m a) not useful?

Tags: haskell, monadplus

I was inspired to play with FizzBuzz after [taking a gander at codepad.org](http://codepad.org/fizzbuzz), and found myself wanting some function:

```
mwhen :: MonadPlus m => Bool -> a -> m a
mwhen b = if b then return else const mzero
```

just so I could do `` mwhen (n /? 3) "Foo" `mappend` mwhen (n /? 5) "Bar" ``

I expected it to be up on hoogle, but [no dice](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=MonadPlus+m+%3D%3E+Bool+-%3E+a+-%3E+m+a).

Is this not as useful as I'd think it'd be?

Comment: Is is just me or there seems to be a lot of haskell question saying "I haven't found it on Hoogle.  So is it useful?". I did it myself. Answers are nonetheless interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mwhen b a` is exactly `guard b >> return a`. When you're doing more things after the `guard`, you normally would have bound the a before the mwhen and not need the return. So mwhen's usefulness seems to be mostly saving a few keystrokes at the end of do-blocks.

Answer (score 1):

A reason it does not exists is, that there is usually no need for this combinator. You can simply overwrite the result of a `when` with `<$` or `>>`, and as you usually have many other monadic operations after a `when`.